# Cannot find ExtensionContext

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm using Flex Builder 4.6 in WinXP, but the line

import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

will get an error message. Why?

Comment: Do you write application using Adobe AIR?

Comment: NO. I'm trying to run an old Web app (SWF) on iOS. It's big and not possible to adapt it to an AIR app, so I directly packed the SWF file to IPA format using some command line tools. But now it needs to do some job which can only be done in Xcode. Don't know how to do it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Native Extensions for Adobe AIR are code libraries that contain native
>   code wrapped with an ActionScript API. You can use native extensions
>   in an AIR application to access platform features not supported by
>   AIR, to benefit from native-code-level performance for critical
>   algorithms, and to reuse existing native code libraries.

[Developing Native Extensions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html)

You can write Native Extensions only for Adobe AIR

Comment: Thanks. It seems so. I have to new a Flex Mobile Project to do the job.